# Storing a Lisp compiled function in a database

Tags: binary, lisp, persistence, common-lisp, clisp

CLISP allows us to do

```
(compile nil #'(lambda(x) (+ x 1)))
```

This returns a compiled function object:

```
#<COMPILED-FUNCTION NIL>
```

Is it possible to export this as a binary string, in order to persist it? Say, saving it in a database, and later be able to load and run the compiled function.

Comment: IIIRC the hu.dwim guy's have a library to even serialize closures to disk, but  I don't recall which one was it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### CLISP

Yes, in CLISP you can:

```
> (defparameter *my-function* (compile nil #'(lambda(x) (+ x 1))))
*MY-FUNCTION*
> *MY-FUNCTION*
#<COMPILED-FUNCTION NIL>
> (write-to-string *my-function* :readably t :pretty nil)
"#Y(|COMMON-LISP|::|NIL| #15Y(00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 20 02 AD 32 B1 19 02) () (|COMMON-LISP|::|T| |COMMON-LISP|::|NIL| |COMMON-LISP|::|NIL|))"
> (defparameter *my-function-1* (read-from-string (write-to-string *my-function* :readably t)))
*MY-FUNCTION-1*
> (funcall *my-function-1* 10)
11
```

This is portable across all platforms supported by CLISP, and as long as the CLISP bytecode version is the same (it does not change at every release).

### Other implementations

As Rainer said, other CL implementation do not necessarily support this, but you can certainly put your function into a file, compile the file, and read in the string:

```
(defun function-string (func)
  (let ((lambda-expr (function-lambda-expression func)))
    (unless lambda-expr
      (error "no lambda expression for ~S" func))
    (let ((tmp-file "tmp.lisp") comp-file ret)
      (with-open-file (o tmp-file :direction :output)
        (write (list* 'defun my-tmp-func (cdr lambda-expr))
               :stream o :readably t))
      (setq comp-file (compile-file tmp-file))
      (with-open-file (compiled comp-file :direction :input
                                :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))
        (setq ret (make-array (file-length compiled)
                              :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8)))
        (read-sequence ret compiled))
      (delete-file tmp-file)
      (delete-file comp-file)
      ret)))
```

To recover the function, you would need to do use [`load`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_load.htm):

```
(with-input-from-string (s (function-string *my-function*))
  (load s))
(fdefinition 'my-tmp-func)
```

**Notes**:

1. [`function-lambda-expression`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_fn_lam.htm)'s value can legitimately be *always* `nil` in a given implementation!
2. If the implementation compiles to native code, the above string will be platform-dependent.
3. I glossed over the package issues...

Comment: I would guess this is portable using CLISP on different operating systems, using the same version number of CLISP?

Comment: yes, this is portable within a given CLISP byte-code version.

Comment: @sds So even upgrading clisp might ruin it?

Comment: @Sylwester: highly unlikely

Comment: @sds: which makes it a feature not supported by many other Lisp implementations when they are generating native code.

Comment: @RainerJoswig: I am afraid I don't understand you.

Comment: @sds: just saying that CLISP byte code is portable across architectures and operating systems, while the code generated by most other implementations is not.

Comment: @RainerJoswig There are several ways to work around this. Especially since you could easily just store the code and make the systems eval and compile it on the go, but a way to do it without using the compiler would be to store different architecture blobs like most apps are packaged today.

Comment: Be very careful with this.  Although CLisp's bytecode itself is portable, some macro expansions may be, and many are, platform dependent.

Comment: @sds thanks, both ways work great in clisp 2.49. Would you say the second strategy would also work with ecl, which seems to compile the file in a binary format directly?

Comment: it depends on the behavior of `function-lambda-expression` in ecl.

Answer (score 5):

Not in portable Common Lisp.

Instead write the function to a file, compile the file with `COMPILE-FILE`. Then you have the compiled code on the file system. You can later load the file and run the function. You could also store the file contents into the database. If you need it later, you would need to export the data from the database into a file and call `LOAD` to load the file.